Why are `dict_keys`, `dict_values`, and `dict_items` not subscriptable?
Referring to an item of a dict_keys, dict_values, or dict_items object by index raises a type error. For example:
> my_dict = {"foo": 0, "bar": 1, "baz": 2}
> my_dict.items()[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 my_dict.items()[0]

TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable

My question is not how to address this. I am aware that one can just call list() or tuple() on a  dict_keys, dict_values, or dict_items object and then subscript that.
My question is why does this behaviour still persist in python given that the order of items in a dictionary has been guaranteed since python 3.7.0. Why is it not possible (or not desirable) to refactor the dict_keys, dict_values, and dict_items types so that they are subscriptable?
The documentation for the stdlib describes these types as "view objects". I imagine that is where the answer to my question lies but I can't find a more detailed description of what a "view object" actually is. Can anyone enlighten me on this matter as well?

Not sure there's a satisfactory answer here. Before dicts were guaranteed to be ordered, accessing elements in it by offset didn't make any practical sense. So dicts were never used as ordered data structures. Just because this has changed now, personally I've never had to rely on dict order anywhere yet. For ordered value pairs, there's the good ol' list-o'-tuples. So perhaps nobody has ever reviewed this policy because of this. Or there may be good arguments against implementing it; it's not really very apropos for SO to dig up such discussions.

The items method returns a view, which reflects the current state of the dictionary. But dictionaries are not simple arrays so subscripting does not make much sense. For full details see https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping.

@OldBoy Unfortunately that in itself doesn't really explain anything, and I think OP already got this far.

If you print(my_dict.items()) you get dict_items([('foo', 0), ('bar', 1), ('baz', 2)]). It looks like a list of tuples - but I guess it's not. The "dict_items" is a view object, with some internal representation, not a real list. If you want to get the "nth" item, the best I could think of was next(itertools.islice(iter(my_dict), n, n+1)).

I think the underlying data structure is not the reason. For example, deque is a linked list, but it is subscriptable even though it is an O(n) operation.

I think this was just a design decision. Even though retaining order makes indexing meaningful, they didn't feel like adding it. I think they were basically just codifying a CPython implementation feature, and it didn't have indexing.

@Toyota Seems like you added the wrong tag so I fixed it. Just letting you know

I didn't know  about dictview. Thank.

It's worth pointing out that dicts themselves don't have a method to select by index. Compare that to Pandas objects, which have .iloc to select by position while __getitem__ or .loc select by label.

@ken: The intended use cases are different. Peeking the first or last element of a deque is extremely common. Accessing, say, the second or third item is much less common, but still a lot more common in the use cases deques are designed for than access by index is in the use cases dicts are designed for. Indexing provides a level of convenience for these operations that the people involved decided was worth it. (Also, the linked list underlying a deque is unrolled, which speeds up indexing significantly relative to iteration.)

@user2357112 What I meant to say is that if it is considered to provide enough benefit, "it's not a proper container class for it" cannot be the reason. I am not literally comparing it to deque. I would not say that indexing dict views provides enough benefit, though.

"Ordered" doesn't mean "efficiently indexable". There is no more efficient way to retrieve the Nth item of a dict view than to iterate N steps.
Allowing indexing would give the impression that views can support this operation efficiently, which would in turn encourage extremely inefficient code. Trying to change the implementation so indexing is efficient would make other dict operations much less efficient, which isn't worthwhile for the use cases dicts are actually designed for.

"There is no more efficient way..." - But there could be. So why isn't it done?

@nocomment: That would require making other operations far more expensive. O(n) dict removals are not a price worth paying for this.

Could be done in O(log n). But yes, I think that's part of the reason and would be good to cover in the answer.

Are you sure about this? My understanding is that the entries table could just be indexed.

@juanpa.arrivillaga: Removal leaves holes, plus the API also needs to make sense for collections.OrderedDict, which uses a completely different system for tracking order. Split-table dicts also have their own concerns.

In a very specific subset of cases, it could be possible to directly index dk_entries, but performance would be highly fragile. Changes in either the dict implementation or the code relying on indexing could cause performance to abruptly degrade to O(n). The devs don't want to design interfaces that encourage fragile code.

ahh yes. so there could be empty markers in the entries table, so you still have to walk the table to get the nth item

Your logic sounds reasonable, but then wouldn't it be wrong for the list to have insert?

@ken: Insertion, while inefficient, is too common an operation to reasonably leave out for lists, and trying to replicate the functionality without built-in support is incredibly cumbersome and even more inefficient. In contrast, entry access by position is highly uncommon in the use cases dict views are designed for, and better alternatives are readily available for such use cases.

@user2357112 If you think that the difference is whether it is common or not, and that being common is a sufficient reason to implement something even if it is inefficient, then your answer should be "because it is not common". Efficiency is just a drawback, not the reason. Probably a lot of people here are stacked there, while I can completely agree with your opinion, but the only answer we can give is an opinion-based answer of "there is no benefit to implementing it".

@ken: Frequency is a factor, but the point about alternatives is more important. Leaving out positional access for dict views encourages people to use better alternatives. Leaving out insertion for lists would force people to use worse alternatives.

And the availability of alternatives is a major part of the frequency thing - people would be trying to access dict entries by position a lot more if the alternative of using lists wasn't right there.

@user2357112 The same thing can be said from the opposite perspective, if you leave out insertion for lists, people might use a better alternative than insertion, and if you leave out positional access for dict views, people might use a worse alternative (in fact, OP's suggested method might be one of the examples).
